# History of Danish "nd" and "ld"

Tags: etymology, orthography

Danish orthography often has "nd" and "ld" instead of "nn" and "ll", often in cases where it is not etymologically justified. Does anybody know more about this, like when this kind of spelling started appearing? Tak!

Comment: I wondered if it might be connected to stød, but after Googling it seems it probably isn't. In any case, I found a resource that might be useful: https://books.google.com/books?id=6b7WwBC5tRAC&pg=PA1388&lpg=PA1388&dq=Danish+spelling+nd+ld+stod&source=bl&ots=Pm9k3GOsyY&sig=kd0WkroxbZvhGrt0iIrdh9UgyYw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiv4qDr4nOAhVM-GMKHUKyAEgQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=Danish%20spelling%20nd%20ld%20stod&f=false

Comment: Whoever voted to close this, please read the guidelines properly: "Language-specific questions are off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage." *This is not a usage question.* If we banned all questions about particular languages, Linguistics.se would be very barren indeed...

Comment: Thanks! I checked the book you recommended, and according to Skautrup (1947) this kind of unetymological spelling was adopted by Christiern Pedersen around the 16th century.